# Adding buttons to soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to add the keys <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> to the soft keyboard but I can't find a way to do it. Does anybody knows if it is possible?

Comment: look into inputType and imeOption for editText and try to get a solution , otherwise a custom keyboard is alot of work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don`t directly add the buttons to the keyboard. But on the EditText you hint that the input will be an e-mail address and IF the available keyboard have the layout with it, it will show.

You want to set the input type on the XML (or by code should work too) to be `textEmailAddress`

Comment: Do you know how can I add "#"?

Comment: it's a symbol not used on any of the standard data types (e.g. email, web page, telefone, address). So the answer is: I don't think you can. The user will have to tap on the symbols page of the keyboard to use it.